# Change a key if it does not exists, depending by the source

Tags: javascript

I have an application with search functionality.
It looks like this:

```js
  const arr1 = [
    {
      name: "Bill"
    },
    {
      name: "Jim"
    }
  ];
  const arr2 = [
    {
      title: "Jack"
    },
    {
      title: "Bill"
    }
  ];
  const arr3 = [
    {
      alias: "Bob"
    }
  ];
 const a = document.getElementById('s');
    a.addEventListener('change', search)

  function search  (e) {
    const res = arr1.filter(i => {
      return i.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(e.target.value) > -1;
    });
    console.log(res);
  };
```

```html
<input id='s' />
```

Now the search woks fine. But i want to make it more flexible. I want when i will change the fultered `array`, to make the search working, because if now if i will change `arr1.filter(i ..` to `arr2.filter(i` i won't get a result because i don't have `i.name.` in `arr2`. The same situation is with `arr3`.
 How to change my code in such a way that it to be able to search in every array if i will change the filtered source?

Comment: Why is your data structured this way?  Shouldn't a person's name, title, and alias be all in the same object?  Also, is there a reason you can't just concatenate all the arrays and search its values?

Comment: @jmargolisvt, I just simulated my case. In my project i also have many sources, and depending by the page where search is located, it should work. So i can't change the arrays. I need a way to interpret `alias`, and `title` as `name`. Do you know how?

Comment: Your data structure seems strange. The implementation would strongly depend on your need. You could simply do OR checks but that would imply key priority such as:
return (i.name || i.title || i.alias).toLowerCase().indexOf(e.target.value) > -1;

Do you wish to filter through multiple arrays at once or will you dynamically change the target array ?

You could also create a search function that takes both an array and a key to search for such as:
function searchForKeyInArray(key, array) {}
passing it 'name' and arr1, then 'title' and arr2...

Comment: @JDubuis, `Do you wish to filter through multiple arrays at once or will you dynamically change the target array ? `. the array  will be changed dynamically

Comment: do you know in advance which array do you like to use?

Answer (score 0):

There can be 2 approaches for this problem, first being concatenating arrays.
Implementation is done below.
Try using:

```
 const arr1 = [
    {
      name: "Bill"
    },
    {
      name: "Jim"
    }
  ];
  const arr2 = [
    {
      title: "Jack"
    },
    {
      title: "Bill"
    }
  ];
  const arr3 = [
    {
      alias: "Bob"
    }
  ];
 const combined = arr1.concat(arr2).concat(arr3);
 const a = document.getElementById('s');
    a.addEventListener('change', search)

  function search  (e) {
    const res = combined.filter(i => {
         if(i.name){
         return i.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(e.target.value).toLowerCase() > -1;}
         if(i.title)
           {
            return i.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(e.target.value).toLowerCase() > -1;
           }
           if(i.alias)
           {
            return i.alias.toLowerCase().indexOf(e.target.value).toLowerCase() > -1;
           }
    });
    console.log(res);
  };
```

The second approach being:

```
const arr1 = [
    {
      name: "Bill"
    },
    {
      name: "Jim"
    }
  ];
  const arr2 = [
    {
      title: "Jack"
    },
    {
      title: "Bill"
    }
  ];
  const arr3 = [
    {
      alias: "Bob"
    }
  ];
 const a = document.getElementById('s');
    a.addEventListener('change', search)

  function search  (e) {
    let res = arr1.filter(i => {
      return i.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(e.target.value) > -1;
    });
    if(res.length > 0){
     res = arr2.filter(i => {
      return i.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(e.target.value) > -1;
    });
    }
    if(res.length > 0){
     res = arr3.filter(i => {
      return i.alias.toLowerCase().indexOf(e.target.value) > -1;
    });
    }
    console.log(res);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.values` to get value of object

---

```
const res = arr1.filter(i => {
  return ...Object.values(i).toLowerCase().indexOf(e.target.value) > -1;
});
```

Comment: If search is performed across ***certain*** properties only, unwanted matches within other properties may return misleading result

Comment: so you might use `entries` instead `values` and also check for some keys

Answer (score 0):

Based on your response in comments here is an approach to filter through your values depending on your array.

```js
const names = [
  {
    name: 'John'
  }
];

const titles = [
  {
    title: 'Doctor'
  }
];

const aliases = [
  {
    alias: 'One eye\'d Jim'
  }
];

const categoryToSearchOptions = function(category) {
  let key;
  switch(category) {
    case 'names':
      return {key: 'name', values: names };
    case 'titles':
      return {key: 'title', values: titles };
    case 'aliases':
      return {key: 'alias', values: aliases };
  }
}

const filter = function(values, key, value) {
  if (!value.length) return [];
  return values.filter(function(item) {
    return item[key].toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) > -1;
  }).map(function(item) { return item[key]; });
};

const appendResult = function(r) {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerText = r;
  document.getElementById('results').appendChild(li);
  
}

const onUpdate = function(e) {
  const options = categoryToSearchOptions(document.getElementById('category').value);
  const results = filter(options.values, options.key, document.getElementById('search').value);
  document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = '';
  results.forEach(appendResult);
}

document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('input', onUpdate);
document.getElementById('category').addEventListener('change', onUpdate);
```

```html
<input id="search" type="text" />
<select id="category">
  <option value="names">Names</option>
  <option value="titles">Titles</option>
  <option value="aliases">Aliases</option>
</select>
<ul id="results"></ul>
```